# Promote Class to Manifest?

Tags: scala

Given the following in Scala v. 2.10.4:

```
trait Parent

case class Boy extends Parent

class Blah[A <: Parent](implicit m: scala.reflect.Manifest[A]) { ... }
```

I tried to make a new `Foo` by explicitly passing the `Manifest[A]` argument.

```
scala> res36
res45: Class[_] = class Boy

scala> new Blah()(res36)
<console>:16: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Class[_$1] where type _$1
 required: scala.reflect.Manifest[?]
              new Blah()(res36)
                         ^
```

How can I instantiate a new `Foo`, but pass in the `Manifest[A]` argument directly?

Answer (score 1):

I might be confused as to what you're trying to accomplish, but normally in this situation, where there is no argument, one would provide a type parameter to the constructor, which would provide enough information to automatically create the implicit.

```
class Blah[A <: Parent](implicit m: Manifest[A]) {
  // ...m will be populated..
}

new Blah[Boy]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. A `Class[_]` contains strictly less information than a `Manifest[_]`, since the manifest also sort of retains type parameters.

So you cannot conjure up a `Manifest` if you're only given a `Class`: you don't have the necessary information.

Comment: Could you please say more on this point, `manifest also sort of retains type parameters`? I didn't understand.

Comment: `Manifest` has a [typeArguments method](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/index.html#scala.reflect.Manifest@typeArguments:List%5Bscala.reflect.Manifest%5B_%5D%5D) which gives you the manifests of its (actual) type arguments. This is an information stored in manifests by the Scala compiler, *in addition* to the runtime `Class`. `Class` doesn't have that, so you cannot reconstruct a `Manifest` at runtime from a `Class`, since you cannot know what are these `typeArguments`.

Comment: Just because a `Manifest[_]` can track type parameters, it doesn't mean that it will always provide type parameter information. If the type system can represent `MyTypedClass[_,_]`, manifests must also represent wildcard type parameters, which is what a `Class[_]` for a class with type parameters would turn into.